# SuspendCoroutine code not reachable when using with Firebase auth

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-authentication, kotlin-coroutines, android-architecture-components

I have a suspendCoroutine in my repository with which I want to send data back to my ViewModel -

```
suspend fun sendPasswordResetMail(emailId: String): Boolean {
        return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            suspendCoroutine { cont ->
                firebaseAuth?.sendPasswordResetEmail(emailId)
                    ?.addOnCompleteListener {
                        cont.resume(it.isSuccessful)
                    }
                    ?.addOnFailureListener {
                        cont.resumeWithException(it)
                    }
            }
        }
    }
```

However, neither of the listeners are called. Debugger says no executable code found at line where 'cont.resume(it.isSuccessful)' or 'cont.resumeWithException(it)' are.

I tried 'Dispatchers.IO', 'Dispatchers.Main' and 'Dispatchers.Default' but none of them seem to work. What could I be doing wrong?

My ViewModel code -

```
isEmailSent : LiveData<Boolean> = liveData {
                emit(firebaseAuthRepo.sendPasswordResetMail(emailId))
            }
```

and

fragment -

```
viewModel.isEmailSent.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, { flag ->
                onResetMailSent(flag)
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are calling

```
isEmailSent : LiveData<Boolean> = liveData {
            emit(firebaseAuthRepo.sendPasswordResetMail(emailId))
        }
```

this piece of code everytime for sending email
and

```
viewModel.isEmailSent.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, { flag ->
            onResetMailSent(flag)
        })
```

this piece only once.

Assuming that's true what you are essentially observing is the initial live data that was created with the model while it is being replaced everytime when resent is called. Instead call

```
isEmailSent.postValue(firebaseAuthRepo.sendPasswordResetMail(emailId))
```

from inside of a coroutine.

Also for the debugger not showing anything try adding a log above the `cont.resume` call and `cont.resumeWithException` call since it has worked for me in the past.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easier way to achieve this is by using `firebase-ktx` and the `await()` function (which does what you are trying under the hood):

```
suspend fun sendPasswordResetMail(emailId: String): Boolean {
     try {
         firebaseAuth?.sendPasswordResetEmail(emailId).await()
         return true
     } catch(e: Exception) {
         return false
     }
}
```

Another way would be to use flow:

```
suspend fun sendPasswordResetMail(emailId: String): Boolean = flow<Boolean {
   firebaseAuth?.sendPasswordResetEmail(emailId).await()
   emit(true)
}.catch { e: Exception -> handleException(e) }
```

You could then observe this in your fragment by putting the code inside your viewmodel and calling `.asLiveData()`